# Angular Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' 'path'

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, import, export

I want to use [opusscript](https://github.com/abalabahaha/opusscript) in my Angular application.

I'm getting the following errors when I start the application

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_wasm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\DriveCode\UserPortal\node_modules\opusscript\build'
ERROR in ./node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_nasm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\DriveCode\UserPortal\node_modules\opusscript\build'
ERROR in ./node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_wasm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\DriveCode\UserPortal\node_modules\opusscript\build'
ERROR in ./node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_nasm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\DriveCode\UserPortal\node_modules\opusscript\build'
```

I had previously executed following commands:

```
npm i opusscript
npm i @types/node
```

In my component ts, I import as:

```
import OpusScript = require('opusscript');
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "preserveWhitespaces": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.app.json is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The index.d.ts in opusscript library has:

```
class OpusScript {
   ...
}
export = OpusScript;
```

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a node.js library and not intended to be used by Angular or any other web framework.

Your best bet, is to use the library on a node.js server and expose it via API. Basically angular runs in the browser and not on the server (on a machine). Therefore there is no access to the file system, which a node js application coudl access.

The node module that is required to run oppusscript is [this: FS module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). There is absolutely no point in using the opusscript js library by importing the fs module too, as you won't be able to access the files from the browser due to security reasons. (js is isolated, and can't access filesystems or execute applications).

Comment: Thank you. Why does the author then mention about typescript in the example?

Comment: Typescript is not an angular exclusive.It is transpiled to javascript. Check https://blog.risingstack.com/building-a-node-js-app-with-typescript-tutorial/ on how to use typescript with node.js